# how to select anyone date using radio button

Tags: android

I am creating new app and this app is pregnancy and I want to select one date and I have last date and due date but I want to select using radio button and select.
    Please help me
    Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
radioGroup_date = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_Date);
radioGroup_date.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {

                int selectedId = radioGroup_date.getCheckedRadioButtonId();//new
                radioButton_date = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);//new
                String text = radioButton_date.getText().toString();//new
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//new

            }
        });

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        editText_calander.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //DateDialog();
                showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);
            }
        });

        button_Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dob = editText_calander.getText().toString();

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("dob", dob);
                editor.commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();

//                int selectedId = radioGroup_date.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
//                radioButton_date = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                b.putString("baby_name", editText_baby_name.getText().toString());
                b.putString("mother_name", editText_mother_name.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtras(b);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Comment: yes, i want to select any one date from radio button 1. last date 2.due date and if user select last date than add 40 weeks and display due date another activity and if user want to select direct due date than display another activity

Comment: `but I want to select using radio button and select` it is completely unclear what you want.

Comment: i hope now you understand very well.

Comment: Can u post ur full java class

Comment: ok,see my java code\

Answer (score 0):

Use radio button is checked or not

```
if(radioButton1.isChecked())
{
  //add last date  
}
else
{
  //add due date
}
```

Comment: Can u post your xml file

Comment: You need to check which radio button in selected using isChecked() function according to that you need to check condition

Comment: i am post my xml in answer ok

Answer (score 0):

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2">


            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radio_Date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/last_date"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/last_date" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/due_date"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/due_date" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/edit_calander"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="9"
                    android:hint="Calander"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_baby_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Baby Name" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_mother_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Mother Name" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_submit"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Submit"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RadioGroup radioGroup_date;
    RadioButton radioButton_date;
    EditText editText_baby_name;
    TextView editText_calander;
    EditText editText_mother_name;
    Button button_Submit;
    // private String cabinChoice;

    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;

   String last_Date,due_date;

    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    static final int DATE_PICKER_ID = 1;
    String dob;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);

        radioGroup_date = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_Date);
        editText_baby_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_baby_name);
        editText_mother_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_mother_name);
        button_Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_submit);
        editText_calander = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_calander);

//        int selectedId = radioGroup_date.getCheckedRadioButtonId();//new
//        radioButton_date = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);//new
        radioGroup_date.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, @IdRes int checkedId) {

                int selectedId = radioGroup_date.getCheckedRadioButtonId();//new
                radioButton_date = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);//new
                String text = radioButton_date.getText().toString();//new
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//new

            }
        });

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        editText_calander.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //DateDialog();
                showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);
            }
        });

        button_Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dob = editText_calander.getText().toString();

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString("dob", dob);
                editor.commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();

//                int selectedId = radioGroup_date.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
//                radioButton_date = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                b.putString("baby_name", editText_baby_name.getText().toString());
                b.putString("mother_name", editText_mother_name.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtras(b);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_PICKER_ID:
                // open datepicker dialog.
                // set date picker for current date
                // add pickerListener listner to date picker
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month, day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                              int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;
            // Show selected date
            editText_calander.setText(new StringBuilder().append(year).append("-")
                    .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day));//old
        }
    };
}
```